# Invalid literal for int() Python

Tags: python, string, int

I got invalid literal for int() in Python but it is really weird because the literal is "1". Of course if I try in IPython int("1") or int(u"1") I have no errors but in my own code the same instruction gives an error.

```
        try:
            VimsLog().debug("val = %s" % val)
            int(val)
        except Exception, e:
            VimsLog().debug(e)
            VimsLog().debug("I am died")
            return val
```

Where

```
e=invalid literal for int(): "1"
```

For reason of compatibility I'm using Python 2.4

Comment: where does this "val" comes from ?

Comment: Try `VimsLog().debug("val = %r" % val)`. What is logged?

Comment: The "val" can probably have a string representation "1", but it cannot be converted to integer. Does int(str(val)) work?

Comment: Did you cut&paste the error message?

Comment: Try `repr(val)` and `dir(val)` to get more information.

Comment: repr(val) gives u'"1"' which if tried in a console gives the error. How can I solve the problem? Val is a value from outside, I have no control over it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `repr(val)` gives `u'"1"'`

this means you're not converting `1`, you're trying to convert `"1"` (i.e. the string quote, 1, quote). That's not a valid integer literal.

Strip the quotes:

```
int(val.strip('"'))
```

Comment: Maybe but that would also remove quotes inside of the string which might allow invalid input to slip through unnoticed: `"1""2"` <- Someone forgot a comma in the input. My code detects this, your code processes `12`

Comment: Ok, then I'll adopt your solution, thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

I've tried all there upper solutions but it's just not working. 
Instead, for me it worked:

```
val = "15.1234"
int(float(str(val)))
```

result

```
>>15
```